# Axios cancel token not working. How can i fix it?

Tags: reactjs, axios

So basically I'm using axios to make requests to a backend and i'd like to limit the number of requests. I am using the axios cancelToken but it is not working for some reason. Here is my code

```
export const useDataQuery = (query, offset) => {
const token = useSelector(state => state.auth.access)
useEffect(() => {
    let cancel;
    axios({
        method: 'GET',
        url: 'http://localhost:8000/api/data/',
        params: { search: query, offset: offset },
        headers: { Authorization: `JWT ${token}` },
        cancelToken: new axios.CancelToken(c => cancel = c)
    }).then(res => {
        console.log(res.data)
    })

    return () => {
        console.log('cancel it');
        console.log(cancel());
        cancel();
    }
}, [query, offset, token])
```

}
I don't know whats wrong here. When i console log the cancel function it prints undefined. I have checked other solutions but none work. So my question is what is wrong here? Thank You!

Answer (score 1):

You need to store the object returned by `axios.CancelToken.source()` which has two properties: `cancel` method and cancel `token`.

Example:

```
useEffect(() => {
    const cancelTokenSource = axios.CancelToken.source()
    axios({
        method: 'GET',
        url: 'http://localhost:8000/api/data/',
        params: { search: query, offset: offset },
        headers: { Authorization: `JWT ${token}` },
        cancelToken: cancelTokenSource.token
    }).then(res => {
        console.log(res.data)
    })

    return () => {
        console.log('cancel it');
        cancelTokenSource.cancel();
    }
}, [query, offset, token])
```

Comment: I've already tried this. It doesn't seem to work I don't understand why. The cancel function runs but it doesn't run every time which is what i can't debug

Comment: There would be some mistake then, can you create a sandbox with this problem? We can use any open API URL for test it with axios.